# Variable Substitution - Reference not working

Tags: powershell

I have this code to test GUI building in PowerShell and i want to make it shorter by making a function to create a label or a button in order to simplify adding more of these afterwards.
What i want to test here is making it so that when i press button 1, it changes the text of label 1. But i cannot get that to work. This is my code:

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "Test1"
$main_form.Width = 250
$main_form.Height = 250

function add-Label
{
param($LabelNum, $LabelText)
$script:Label_Current = New-Variable -Name "Label_{$LabelNum}" -Value $LabelNum -Force -PassThru
$script:Label_Current = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

$script:Label_Current.Name = "Label_$LabelNum"
$script:Label_Current.Text = "$LabelText"
$LabelHeight = 1+ $LabelNum * 50
$script:Label_Current.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$LabelHeight)

$main_form.Controls.Add($script:Label_Current)
}

function add-Button
{
param($ButtonNum, $ButtonText)
$Button_Current = New-Variable -name "Button_{$ButtonNum}" -Value $ButtonNum -Force -PassThru
$Button_Current = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button_Current.Text = "$ButtonText"
$ButtonHeight = 1+ $ButtonNum * 50
$Button_Current.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$ButtonHeight)
$Button_Current.Add_Click({$Label_Current.Text = "Test10"})
$main_form.Controls.Add($Button_Current)
}

add-Label -LabelNum 0 -LabelText "Test3"
add-Label -LabelNum 1 -LabelText "Test3"
add-Label -LabelNum 2 -LabelText "Test3"
add-Label -LabelNum 3 -LabelText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 0 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 1 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 2 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 3 -ButtonText "Test3"


$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

When i run it as it is right now, all Buttons will only change the last Label that was added.
When i tell it to change the Text of a specific number (`$Button_Current.Add_Click({$Label_1.Text = "Test10"})` it will say "Object not found"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your buttons only change the last label, because your last label is the value of "$Label_Current".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit of a "clever" solution, rather than an "easy to understand and maintain" solution, but I've added it anyway because it uses something I didn't know about before I started researching this answer - i.e. the [ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=pscore-6.2.0) method:

```bsh
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

function New-Label
{
    param($LabelNum, $LabelText)
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Name = "Label_$LabelNum"
    $label.Text = $LabelText
    $LabelY = 1 + $LabelNum * 50
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $LabelY)
    return $label
}

function New-Button
{
    param($ButtonNum, $ButtonText)
    $button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $button.Text = $ButtonText
    $ButtonY = 1 + $ButtonNum * 50
    $button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, $ButtonY)
    return $button
}

function New-Form
{

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.Text = "Test1"
    $form.Width = 250
    $form.Height = 250

    # create an array of labels
    $labels = 0..3 | % {
        New-Label -LabelNum $_ -LabelText "label_$($_)"
    }

    # add the labels to the form
    $labels | % { $form.Controls.Add($_) }

    # create an array of buttons
    $buttons = 0..3 | % {
        New-Button -ButtonNum $_ -ButtonText "button_$($_)"
    }

    # add the buttons to the form
    $buttons | % { $form.Controls.Add($_) }

    # add event handlers onto the buttons
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $buttons.Length; $i++ )
    {
        $buttons[$i].Add_Click(
            { $labels[$i].Text = $buttons[$i].Text }.GetNewClosure()
        )
    }
    return $form
}

$main_form = New-Form
$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

I've done a couple of things that (to my mind) simplify your code by removing references to global variables inside the functions. Instead of the functions adding labels and buttons to `$main_form` themselves, they just return an independent label or button and let the calling code decide to do with it.

The "clever" (but maybe not so "smart") bit is using `GetNewClosure` in `New-Form` - first we create parallel arrays of labels and buttons, and then zip them together to create the event handlers.

This has the advantage that you don't need to "find" the labels and buttons again by name after you create them because you keep references to them in the arrays, but it's got the disadvantage that it uses `GetNewClosure` which isn't easy to explain what it's actually doing!

I think the [answer by Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934879/3156906) might be more pragmatic, but here's some links to documentation for `GetNewEnclosure` in case you want to read up on it...

- devblogs.microsoft.com - [Get closure with GetNewClosure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/get-closure-with-getnewclosure/)
- rakhesh.com - [Using closure to capture the variable value in a script-block](https://rakhesh.com/powershell/using-closure-to-capture-the-variable-value-in-a-script-block/)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to create new variables for the labels and buttons, you could use the forms own control collection for this and using the label controls name, it is easy enough to target a specific label.

Something like below:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function Add-Label ([int]$index, [string]$labelText) {
    $top  = 1 + $index * 50
    $temp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $temp.Name = "Label$index"
    $temp.Text = $labelText
    $temp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$top)

    $main_form.Controls.Add($temp)
}

function Add-Button ([int]$index, [string]$buttonText, [string]$newLabelText) {
    $top   = 1 + $index * 50
    $temp  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $temp.Text = $buttonText
    $temp.Name = "Button$index"
    $temp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$top)
    # store the new text for the label in the button Tag
    # because inside the Click() method, $newLabelText is unknown
    $temp.Tag = $newLabelText   

    $temp.Add_Click({ 
        # get the index for the label from the buttons name
        $labelIndex = [int]($this.Name -replace '\D')
        # use the Find method to get the wanted label by name
        $main_form.Controls.Find("Label$labelIndex", $true)[0].Text = $this.Tag
    })

    $main_form.Controls.Add($temp)
}

$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text   = "Test1"
$main_form.Width  = 250
$main_form.Height = 250

# add the controls to the form
(0..3) | ForEach-Object { 
    Add-Label $_ "Test$_"
    Add-Button $_ "Button$_" "New Label Text $_" 
}

$main_form.ShowDialog() 

# don't forget to dispose of the form when done !
$main_form.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue like that:

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "Test1"
$main_form.Width = 250
$main_form.Height = 250

$global:LabelArray = @()



function add-Label
{
param($LabelNum, $LabelText)
$Labelvar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelHeight = 1+ $LabelNum * 50
$dynamicVar = "Label_{0}" -f $LabelNum
$CurrentVar = New-variable -Name $dynamicVar -Value $Labelvar -PassThru -Force
$global:LabelArray += $CurrentVar

$global:LabelArray[$LabelNum].Value.Text = "$LabelText"
$global:LabelArray[$LabelNum].Value.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,$LabelHeight)
$main_form.Controls.Add($global:LabelArray[$LabelNum].Value)
}

function add-Button
{
param($ButtonNum, $ButtonText)
$Button_Current = New-Variable -name "Button_{$ButtonNum}" -Value $ButtonNum -Force -PassThru
$Button_Current = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button_Current.Text = "$ButtonText"
$ButtonHeight = 1+ $ButtonNum * 50
$Button_Current.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,$ButtonHeight)

switch($ButtonNum)
{
0 {$Button_Current.Add_Click({write-host $script:LabelArray[0].Value.Text})}
1 {$Button_Current.Add_Click({write-host $script:LabelArray[1].Value.Text})}
2 {$Button_Current.Add_Click({write-host $script:LabelArray[2].Value.Text})}
3 {$Button_Current.Add_Click({write-host $script:LabelArray[3].Value.Text})}
}

$main_form.Controls.Add($Button_Current)
}



add-Label -LabelNum 0 -LabelText "Test1"
add-Label -LabelNum 1 -LabelText "Test2"
add-Label -LabelNum 2 -LabelText "Test3"
add-Label -LabelNum 3 -LabelText "Test4"
add-Button -ButtonNum 0 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 1 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 2 -ButtonText "Test3"
add-Button -ButtonNum 3 -ButtonText "Test3"


$main_form.ShowDialog()
```